# Why it is necessary to pass the anc vector by reference in the dfs function?

Tags: graph, depth-first-search, cycle

```
class Solution
{
    public:
    //Function to detect cycle in a directed graph.
    bool dfs(int V, vector<int> adj[],vector <bool>& isvis,int start,vector<bool>**&**anc)
    {
        isvis[start]=1;
        anc[start]=true;
        for(auto nb : adj[start])
        {   
                
            if(!isvis[nb])
            {
                if(dfs(V,adj,isvis,nb,anc))
                return true;
            }
            
            if(anc[nb]==true)
                return true;
        }
        
        for(int i=0;i<V;i++)
        {
            cout<<i<<" "<<anc[i]<<endl;
        }
        
        anc[start]=false;
        return false;
    }
    bool isCyclic(int V, vector<int> adj[]) 
    {
       vector < bool > isvis(V,false);
       vector <bool> anc(V,false);
       for(int i=0;i<V;i++)
       {
           if(!isvis[i])
           {
               if(dfs(V,adj,isvis,i,anc))
               return true;
           }
       }
       return false;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the function modifies the argument (in `anc[start]=true;`). If it was passed by value, it would have its own copy of the vector and modify that copy, so the `anc` variable in `isCyclic` wouldn't be modified.

Comment: We are just using the anc vector to track the ancestor nodes of the neighbours of adj Why we need it to be modified

Comment: And also I am not getting incorrect answer but I am getting TLE

Comment: Again, because you have `anc[start]=true;` (and also `anc[start]=false;` closer to the end, and the recursive `dfs` call which will also modify the `anc` and `isvis` vectors).

Comment: You can write a different implementation which doesn't do that and then you can pass `anc` by value (but it would be more common to pass it by constant reference to avoid copying).